# How to avoid duplicating UserDetailsService related beans in spring security configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I use spring-mvc with java config and spring-security together.

As it [states in docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#abstractsecuritywebapplicationinitializer-with-spring-mvc) I've put `SecurityConfig.class` into `rootContext`.

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[]{SecurityConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[]{WebConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}

}
```

In security configuration, I need to inject `UserDetailsService` which eventually needs `UserDao` and `SessionFactory`. So I need to add `@ComponentScan({ "my.package" })` in order to make those dependencies available for rootContext.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan({ "my.package" })
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

...

}
```

However those `UserDao` and `SessionFactory` are needed in servletContext as well and in turn they are get created via `WebConfig.class`.

At the end those beans are duplicated and present in both `rootContext` and `servletContext`.

How can I prevent that?

Comment: The `servletContext` can access beans from the `rootContext` so there is no need to scan for them again.

Comment: yes I know, but @ComponentScan takes packages and UserDetailsService and other services are at the same package. So do I need to split those into separate packages just to exclude in `servletContext`?

Comment: Services etc should be loaded by the `rootContext` not the `servletContext`. Your servlet context should only load web related things like controllers. You can use include and exclude filters for that.

Comment: I miss that suggestion or best practice in spring docs, can you please point me to the reference of this practice please?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#testcontext-ctx-management-ctx-hierarchies has some hints.

Comment: thank you, I will be checking out

Comment: how big your app will be? If it's not massive and you plan to have only one Servlet (DispatherServlet) why bother splitting the contexts at all? Just use servlet context and leave root context null.

Comment: @lkrnac you can't do that when using spring-security, can you?

Comment: Why not? Here is sample from Spring Security repo: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/7b4a37f27e4ba7045bd63656e49ee0d5ee381ce5/samples/chat-jc/src/main/java/sample/config/ChatApplicationInitializer.java

Comment: @lkrnac I think they're not using mvc scurity because I couldn't find where they put `WebSecurityConfig` with spring context. But I am not sure. 

In docs they state you need to put `SecurityConfig` in rootContext as I understand.

Comment: They scan it. Look into WebMvcConfiguration. There is component scan in sample package (root package for that example). As WebSecurityConfig is @Configuration, it will be scanned.

Comment: We are using single context approach with Spring Security for our project without any problems.